# Does a plural countable noun mean there are many?

Tags: meaning, plural-forms

Does a plural countable noun mean there are many?

Example 1:

> Helping old people cross the street is satisfying.

Does Example 1 mean helping more than one old person at a time?

Or

Does Example 1 mean helping one old person at a time but can be interpreted as "helping more than one old person at a time" if it meets the context?

---

Example 2:

> Disarming enemy soldiers is his specialty.

Does Example 2 mean disarming more than one enemy soldier at a time?

Or

Does Example 2 mean disarming one enemy soldier at a time but can be interpreted as "disarming more than one enemy soldier at a time" if it meets the context?

Comment: Why would each case not mean 'one or more at a time'?

Comment: In a context like this, the reference is to 'the activity in general'.

Comment: OP, why do you think that the speaker is helping many old people across the street at once? Wouldn't that be weird or hard to do?

Comment: @FeliniusRex It is a question to me because "old people" is plural.

Comment: Wouldn't it be hard for one guy to disarm many different soldiers At The Same Time? Likewise, wouldn't be weird to see one man helping many old people across the street At The Same Time?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Ok, thanks for your explanation. So, those plural forms are just referring to the activity in general and not meaning doing the activity to many old people or many soldiers at the same time.

Comment: @vincentlin Yes - you are correct.